# How to create a Vue Checklist Schedule

Tags: html, list, vue.js, cdn

I am trying to create a simple ordering schedule checklist for each meal of the day using Vuejs cdn and Laravel as my backend.

I was expecting a behavior if All is chosen on Monday breakfast to snack will be also checked.
But what happens is that it checks the entire checkbox.

```js
Vue.component("day-selector", {
template:
            '<table class="table">' +
            '<tr>\n' +
            '    <td>Day</td>\n' +
            '    <td>All</td>\n' +
            '    <td>Breakfast</td>\n' +
            '    <td>Lunch</td>\n' +
            '    <td>Dinner</td>\n' +
            '    <td>Snack</td>\n' +
            '    </tr>\n' +
            '    <tr v-for="items in daySchedule" :key="items.id">\n' +
            '    <td>{{items.dayname}}</td>' +
            '    <td><input type="checkbox" v-model="chooseAll"></td>' +
            '    <td><input type="checkbox" v-model="breakfastOption"></td>' +
            '    <td><input type="checkbox" v-model="lunchOption"></td>' +
            '    <td><input type="checkbox" v-model="dinnerOption"></td>' +
            '    <td><input type="checkbox" v-model="snackOption"></td>' +
            '    </tr>' +
            '    {{orderSchedule}}</table>',
    props: ['day'],
    data:function() {
        return {
            breakfastOption: false,
            lunchOption: false,
            dinnerOption: false,
            snackOption: false,
            daySchedule:[
                {id:'1',dayname:'Monday', breakfastOption:false,lunchOption:false,dinnerOption:false,snackOption:false},
                {id:'2',dayname:'Tusday', breakfastOption:false,lunchOption:false,dinnerOption:false,snackOption:false},
                {id:'3',dayname:'Wednesday', breakfastOption:false,lunchOption:false,dinnerOption:false,snackOption:false},
                {id:'4',dayname:'Thursday', breakfastOption:false,lunchOption:false,dinnerOption:false,snackOption:false},
                {id:'5',dayname:'Friday', breakfastOption:false,lunchOption:false,dinnerOption:false,snackOption:false},
            ],
            orderSchedule:[],
        };
    },
    computed:{
        chooseAll:{
            get() {
                return this.breakfastOption || this.lunchOption || this.dinnerOption || this.snackOption
            },
            set:function (checkedValue) {
                return this.breakfastOption = this.lunchOption = this.dinnerOption = this.snackOption = checkedValue;
            }
        }
    }
});


Vue.component('day-selector-template');



var app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:function(){
        return{
       
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.1/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
   <div class="col-md-5 order-md-3 mb-5">
                <div class="card">
                <day-selector ></day-selector>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

I would want to do something like if I want to only eat lunch on some days and order all in other days and then be able to save it to laravel to make schedules.

[image]

I have attached a fiddle to show the example. 
[Fiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/Metono/rc98qz6s/5/)

Would you be able to help me find a solution on this or if you know another way I can try.

Please Advise, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it's not working, is because you're not using each item's properties, but some global one.

Change your HTML part to this (notice the `items.` and new method called `toggleAll`

```
'    <td><input type="checkbox" @change="toggleAll(items, $event.target.checked)"></td>' +
'    <td><input type="checkbox" v-model="items.breakfastOption"></td>' +
'    <td><input type="checkbox" v-model="items.lunchOption"></td>' +
'    <td><input type="checkbox" v-model="items.dinnerOption"></td>' +
'    <td><input type="checkbox" v-model="items.snackOption"></td>' +
```

Add a method to actually trigger the toggling

```
methods: {
    toggleAll(input, checked) {
      for (let key in input) {
        console.log(typeof input[key] === "boolean")
          if (typeof input[key] === "boolean") {
            input[key] = checked
        }
      }
  }
}
```

and get rid of the useless data properties

```
breakfastOption: false,
lunchOption: false,
dinnerOption: false,
snackOption: false,
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pfkh5bu9/1/

Comment: Oh, wow... I never knew I can bind the things inside the array.  I was always thinking, I always need to bind things in global. Thank you for your help, I learned something new.